# Python Flask app.run is not rechable, IP not showing in terminal

Tags: python, flask

When I run my flask with pycharm python code run well but when it come to app.run() my terminal doesnot show any ip address it directly say unreachable code. I uninstall my python and pycharm and reinstall them the problem is same.I try with visual studio code but the error is same what can i do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOTeK.png)

Comment: Please remove extra two tabs from line number 7, then it should work. If you're new to python I suggest you to learn basics of python and then move to Flask

Answer (score 1):

Your code is close but wrong. The error is because of the indentation.  You have added the `debug=True` to the route, it should be indented from `if __name__ == '__main__'` like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If you are curious about why you should bother with the addition of the `if __name__ == '__main__':`  line then check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) great explanation.